# How to switch view on menu item click?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Hello I am using Windows forms application on visual studio to create a custom application. I want to implement such that when i click a menu item i switch the view to respective view. In below case clicking on Autopilot switches to the autopilot settings etc, or clicking on other menu items switches to respective views.

My Result.

[image]

Comment: Create an AutoPilotUserControl and show it in the form when the menu item is selected.

Comment: Or use TabControl - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol

Answer (score 0):

-Add a panel where you wants to display your interfaces

-Add a new UserControl in your project (ex : ucNavigation)

-Initialise the UserControl in your main form

-Add the UserControl in your pannel form like an other control

---

Add a panel in your main form, from the toolbox if you want.

Right clic in your project --> Add new element --> UserControl (named ucNavigation) and the same for others UC)

```
public partial class frmMCAV : Form
{
    private ucNavigation ucNavigation  = new ucNavigation();
    private ucDebriefing ucDebriefing = new ucDebriefing();
    ...
}


private void menuNavigation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.panelUC.Controls.Clear();
    this.panelUC.Controls.Add(ucAccueil);
}

private void menuDebriefing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.panelUC.Controls.Clear();
    this.panelUC.Controls.Add(ucAccueil);
}
```